# Incrementing a counter when a link is clicked in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following HTML/PHP code:

```
    <img id="imageViewer"src="someData" height="" width="" alt=""></img>
        <?php
            //a counter so we know what image to return
            $counter =0;

            print("<a href='#'>Click me</a>");

            $imageArray = array(0 => "image link", 1 => "image link", 2=>"image link", 3=>"image link");

            if ($counter<= count($imageArray))
            {
                $pathToImage = imageArray[$counter];
            }
            else
            {
                $counter =0;
                $pathToImage = imageArray[$counter];
            }

            //code to replace old image with new image

        ?>
```

How do I increment `$counter` when the link is clicked, and then alter the image to show the new image based on what is selected from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. PHP is a server side script. It's not like JavaScript that is executed live on the client's machine. PHP is executed on the server before sending data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, `$counter` will be `0` every single time the page loads. Remember that all PHP code is translated into HTML *before* the page is rendered in the browser.

Is JavaScript an option? If so, you can dynamically change the `src` by listening to click events. If not, you will need to pass the current image index via `$_GET` or `$_POST` vars.

For example (using `$_GET`)

```
// define array here...

// Get next image
if ( isset($_GET['index'];) )
  $imageIndex = $_GET['index'] + 1;
else
  $imageIndex = 0;

// Show image...
echo '<img src="' . $imageArray[$imageIndex] . '" />';

// Next image link...
echo '<a href="URL?index=' . ($imageIndex + 1) . '">Next</a>';
```

Or something like that.

Comment: how would I do this using Javascript?

Comment: @zPesk you'd send an ajax request to a PHP script which increases the counter, stored in a database.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you're going to be able to do that is if you store the data somehow. If I was doing that I'd use a database, but because it's only a counter let's store the data in a file.

Here are two shortcut functions you can use:

1). To put something into a file use:
file_put_contents("counter.txt",$STRING_YOU_WISH_TO_STORE);

2). To get data from the file 'counter.txt':
$data = file_get_contents("counter.txt");

You'll have to get the data stored in the file, increment it, then write it back each time you run the script.